# Why is my CSS animation not working?

Tags: css, animation

http://jsfiddle.net/m93gLw7o/

Above link is the address of my code.

It's really weird. I stuied at w3school, and I think there is no wrong sentence in my code.

Why this code isn't working?

And below is the code.

**html**

```
<a id="siteLogo" class="siteLogo_ani" href="./">
    <img src="http://goo.gl/QafDup">
</a>
```

**css**

```
.siteLogo_ani {
    -webkit-animation-name: asdf;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-out;
    -webkit-animation-delay: 1;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1;
    -webkit-animation-direction: normal;

    animation-name: asdf;
    animation-duration: 1s;
    animation-timing-function: ease-out;
    animation-delay:1;
    animation-iteration-count: 1;
    animation-direction: normal;
}

@-webkit-keyframes asdf{
    from {float: left; width:355px; height:150px; display:block;}
    to   {float: left; width:160px; height:50px; display:block;}
}
@keyframes asdf{
    from {float: left; width:355px; height:150px; display:block;}
    to   {float: left; width:160px; height:50px; display:block;}
}

#siteLogo img{width:100%; height:100%;}
```

Comment: Is `href="./"` a valid url? And what isn't working?

Comment: the animation isn't working. href is nothing. it's nothing.

Comment: @l2aelba Nah, was just wondering.

Comment: Derp. I was trying to figure it out for a few, then I realized that an anchor is an inline element. Change `.siteLogo_ani` to `display: block;`.

Comment: No.. it's not working. Or maybe the tag that have something inside can not have animation... is it right?

Comment: For some reason, you can't manipulate the `display` property via animations. Referring to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3331353/transitions-on-the-display-property

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, in reference to [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3331353/transitions-on-the-display-property), you are not able to utilize the `display` property via animations. Because of this, I would abstract your `display` property into `.siteLogo_ani` (I also put your ending width in that class, too) like thus:

```
.siteLogo_ani {
    -webkit-animation-name: asdf;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-out;
    -webkit-animation-delay: 1;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1;
    -webkit-animation-direction: normal;

    animation-name: asdf;
    animation-duration: 1s;
    animation-timing-function: ease-out;
    animation-delay:1;
    animation-iteration-count: 1;
    animation-direction: normal;

    display: block;
    float: left;
    width: 160px;
}
```

This will leave your keyframes free to manipulate only one or two properties (and by putting your width in your original class, the keyframe ends at that style and will stay there):

```
@-webkit-keyframes asdf{
    from { width:355px; }
    to   { width:160px; }
}
@keyframes asdf{
    from { width:355px; }
    to   { width: 160px; }
}

#siteLogo img { width:100%; }
```

This way, it makes for a simpler animation, and leaves you with less to manipulate (I also took out a bunch of heights so the image doesn't lose its aspect ratio).

Check it out: http://jsfiddle.net/m93gLw7o/8/

Comment: Thanks. now I know the css animation can not give display property to the object.

Answer (score 1):

Because you're doing the animation to the 'a' tag, not to the image, so check the CSS here:
http://jsfiddle.net/m93gLw7o/1/
You can see that I added the 'img' tag selector. Like so:

```
.siteLogo_ani img{
```

Comment: But I don't know why. if give animation to 'img' tag is possible, than give it to 'a' tag is also possible. isn't it? is 'a' tag can not have a animation? 'div' can have animation, and 'img' can have animation, but why 'a' tag can not have an animation?

Answer (score 0):

You should put ***display:block;*** in ***.siteLogo_ani*** class not in the animaton. It's not working  because a has display:inline in default and does not have an exact width or height to pass to its child elements.